# how to unify 2 tables that have the same origin?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a table with values that have a flow vision (recours) and others with a stock vision (PSAP). I split this table in two in order to transform my flow vision fields into stock vision, it works well but I get stuck when I try to reunify my two tables in one.

I have tried several approaches that you can see in the code below.

Either I generate a new CTE columnsStockFinal in order for it to have the same number of lines that columnsFluxToStock and that I can do a inner join between columnsFluxToStock and columnsStockFinal.

Or I keep columnsStock and I do a full outer join with columnsFluxToStock.

For each missing date, a line must appear with the value of PSAP that represents the last known stock at date for the tuple/key : Silo / GAR / Lob.

That leads to :

For 2023-03-31 / Completude / GAR1 / lob1, I should have the last value of PSAP directly anteriorly available, so for 2023-02-28, that is 2100.

For 2023-03-31 / EDI / GAR1 / lob1, I should have the last value of PSAP directly anteriorly available, so for 2023-02-28, that is 1100.

For 2023-04-30 / EDI / GAR1 / lob1, I should have the last value of PSAP directly anteriorly available, so for 2023-02-28 or for 2023-03-31, that is 1100.

Of course, the values must not be hard-coded.

I must then get the following result :

```
ViewDate    Silo    GAR Lob recours PSAP
2023-01-31  Completude  GAR1    lob1    100 2000
2023-01-31  EDI GAR1    lob1    10  1000
2023-02-28  Completude  GAR1    lob1    150 2100
2023-02-28  EDI GAR1    lob1    15  1100
2023-03-31  Completude  GAR1    lob1    150 2100
2023-03-31  EDI GAR1    lob1    15  1100
2023-04-30  Completude  GAR1    lob1    210 2200
2023-04-30  EDI GAR1    lob1    15  1100
2023-05-31  Completude  GAR1    lob1    280 2300
2023-05-31  EDI GAR1    lob1    21  1200
```

This is the code I made so far with some other tries in comments :

```
drop table if exists ColumnsMixedFluxStock;
CREATE TABLE ColumnsMixedFluxStock (
    ViewDate DATE,
    silo varchar(10),
    GAR varchar(10),
    lob varchar(10),
    recours int,
    PSAP int
);
 
INSERT INTO ColumnsMixedFluxStock VALUES
('2023-01-31', 'EDI', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 10, 1000),
('2023-02-28', 'EDI', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 5, 1100),
        ('2023-05-31', 'EDI', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 6, 1200),
 
('2023-01-31', 'Completude', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 100, 2000),
('2023-02-28', 'Completude', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 50, 2100)
 
        ,('2023-04-30', 'Completude', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 60, 2200),
         ('2023-05-31', 'Completude', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 70, 2300)
;
 
with ColumnsFlux as (
select Silo, ViewDate, GAR, Lob, recours
from ColumnsMixedFluxStock
),
ColumnsStock as (
select Silo, ViewDate, GAR, Lob, PSAP
from ColumnsMixedFluxStock
),
min_max_dates AS (
  SELECT MIN(ViewDate) as min_date, MAX(ViewDate) as max_date
  FROM ColumnsMixedFluxStock
),
date_range AS (
  SELECT explode(sequence(to_date(min_date), to_date(max_date), interval 1 month)) as ViewDate
  FROM min_max_dates
),
columnsFluxToStock AS (
SELECT i1.ViewDate, i2.silo, i2.GAR, i2.Lob,
       SUM(coalesce(i2.recours, 0)) as recours
FROM  ColumnsFlux i2
cross join date_range i1 on 
                   i1.ViewDate >= i2.ViewDate
GROUP BY i1.ViewDate, i2.silo, i2.GAR, i2.Lob
)
 
/*columnsStockFinal AS (
SELECT i1.ViewDate, i2.silo, i2.GAR, i2.Lob,
       coalesce(last_value(i2.PSAP) OVER (PARTITION BY /*i2.ViewDate,*/    i2.silo, i2.GAR, i2.Lob ORDER BY i2.ViewDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), 0) as PSAP
FROM date_range i1
LEFT JOIN ColumnsStock i2 on 
                   i1.ViewDate >= i2.ViewDate
) select * from columnsStockFinal order by ViewDate, Silo, GAR, Lob*/
 
/*all_combinations AS (
  SELECT dr.ViewDate, cs.silo, cs.GAR, cs.Lob
  FROM date_range dr
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT silo, GAR, Lob FROM ColumnsStock) cs
),
columnsStockFinal AS (
  SELECT ac.ViewDate, ac.silo, ac.GAR, ac.Lob,
         COALESCE(LAST_VALUE(cs.PSAP) OVER (PARTITION BY cs.silo, cs.GAR, cs.Lob ORDER BY ac.ViewDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), 0) AS PSAP
  FROM all_combinations ac
  LEFT JOIN ColumnsStock cs ON ac.silo = cs.silo AND ac.GAR = cs.GAR AND ac.Lob = cs.Lob AND ac.ViewDate = cs.ViewDate
) select * from columnsStockFinal order by ViewDate, Silo, GAR, Lob*/
 
/*
columnsStockFinal AS (
SELECT i1.ViewDate, i2.silo, i2.GAR, i2.Lob,
       coalesce(i2.PSAP, 0) as PSAP
FROM  ColumnsStock i2
cross join date_range i1 on 
                   i1.ViewDate = i2.ViewDate
GROUP BY i1.ViewDate, i2.silo, i2.GAR, i2.Lob
) --select * from columnsStockFinal order by ViewDate, Silo, GAR, Lob
*/
 
 
 
/*select cs.Silo, cs.ViewDate, cs.GAR, cs.Lob,
  cfts.recours,
  cs.PSAP
from columnsStockFinal cs  --columnsStock cs 
inner join
--full outer join
--inner join après avoir fait une autre CTE columnsStockFinal avec un cross join de ColumnsStock et date_range
columnsFluxToStock cfts on 
                        cs.Silo = cfts.Silo
                    AND cs.ViewDate = cfts.ViewDate
                            AND cs.GAR = cfts.GAR
                            AND cs.Lob = cfts.Lob
--where recours != 0 or PSAP != 0
order by ViewDate, Silo, GAR, Lob*/
 
select coalesce(cs.Silo, cfts.Silo) as Silo, coalesce(cs.ViewDate, cfts.ViewDate) ViewDate, coalesce(cs.GAR, cfts.GAR) as GAR, coalesce(cs.Lob, cfts.Lob) as Lob,
  cfts.recours,
  cs.PSAP
from columnsStock cs  --columnsStock cs
full outer join
columnsFluxToStock cfts on
                        cs.Silo = cfts.Silo
                    AND cs.ViewDate = cfts.ViewDate
                    AND cs.GAR = cfts.GAR
                    AND cs.Lob = cfts.Lob
--where recours != 0 or PSAP != 0
order by ViewDate, Silo, GAR, Lob
```

Thanks for your help.

I am on Databricks using spark sql.

Comment: Can everything commented out in your query be ignored?

Comment: Also, it'd help if you explain this more in natural language - what exactly does it mean to "transform a flow vision fields into stock vision"? Tough to tell just from a query that isn't actually doing it (and is syntactically incorrect with debugging lines still in the mix). Especially because, I image, these are industry or model specific terms.

Comment: What is in the comments are differents approaches I tried, which might give you hints of how to solve the issue. As to vision flow vs stock difference :

Comment: It is like a kid's wallet. In january, his parents  gave him 100$. He didn't spend anything, so end of january he has 100$ in stock vision and also in flow vision. In February he gets 200$ and doesn't spend anything, so end of february, he has 200$ in flow vision but 300$ in stock vision. In March he doesn't get anything, so stock vision is still 300$ and while flow vision should be 0$, in my data sample, there isn't data at all (but which equals to 0$ in flow vision). I hope it's clearer.

Comment: Makes sense, that was described well. So one is the balance and the other is transactional.

Comment: I guess we can say so indeed. Flow = transactional and Stock = balance Any idea how to solve the issue then ?

Comment: Dropped a solution

Answer (score 0):

This may have some gaps, depending on how representative your sample data is.

Cluttered with some boilerplate for reproducibility/testing. Main solution is in spark sql query for `actual_df`.

Rationale - Use cumulative sum to independently calculate to rolling sum of recours off the original data. Then you can impute your missing dates without needing to account for it in the calculation.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DateType
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, col
from pyspark.testing.utils import assertDataFrameEqual

schema = StructType([
    StructField("viewdate", StringType(), True),
    StructField("silo", StringType(), True),
    StructField("gar", StringType(), True),
    StructField("lob", StringType(), True),
    StructField("recours", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("psap", IntegerType(), True)
])

sample_data = [
    ('2023-01-31', 'EDI', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 10, 1000),
    ('2023-02-28', 'EDI', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 5, 1100),
    ('2023-05-31', 'EDI', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 6, 1200),
    ('2023-01-31', 'Completude', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 100, 2000),
    ('2023-02-28', 'Completude', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 50, 2100),
    ('2023-04-30', 'Completude', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 60, 2200),
    ('2023-05-31', 'Completude', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 70, 2300)
]

expected_data = [
    ('2023-01-31', 'Completude', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 100, 2000),
    ('2023-01-31', 'EDI', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 10, 1000),
    ('2023-02-28', 'Completude', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 150, 2100),
    ('2023-02-28', 'EDI', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 15, 1100),
    ('2023-03-31', 'Completude', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 150, 2100),
    ('2023-03-31', 'EDI', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 15, 1100),
    ('2023-04-30', 'Completude', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 210, 2200),
    ('2023-04-30', 'EDI', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 15, 1100),
    ('2023-05-31', 'Completude', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 280, 2300),
    ('2023-05-31', 'EDI', 'GAR1', 'lob1', 21, 1200)
]

def create_df_with_cleaned_date(data):
  return (
    spark.
    createDataFrame(data, schema=schema).
    withColumn("ViewDate", to_date(col("ViewDate")))
  )

create_df_with_cleaned_date(sample_data).createOrReplaceTempView("sample_vw")
expected_df = create_df_with_cleaned_date(expected_data)

actual_df = spark.sql("""
  with month_ends_in_range as (
    SELECT
      explode(
        sequence(min(ViewDate), max(ViewDate), interval 1 month)
      ) as month_ends
    FROM
      sample_vw
  ),
  cum_sums_calculated as (
    select
      *,
      sum(recours) over (
        PARTITION BY Silo
        ORDER BY
          viewDate rows between unbounded preceding
          and current row) as cum_sum_recours,
      lead(ViewDate, 1, cast('9999-12-31' as date)) over (
        partition by Silo
        order by
          ViewDate
      ) nextViewDate
    from
      sample_vw
  ),
  fill_in_gap_dates as (
    select
      *
    from
      cum_sums_calculated csc
      inner join month_ends_in_range mer 
      on mer.month_ends >= csc.ViewDate
      and mer.month_ends < csc.NextViewDate
  )
  select
    month_ends as ViewDate,
    silo,
    gar,
    lob,
    cast(cum_sum_recours as int) recours,
    psap  
  from
    fill_in_gap_dates
  order by
    ViewDate""")

actual_df.show()
expected_df.show()
assertDataFrameEqual(actual_df, expected_df)
```